# Where does Xtext hold the created objects within the code?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext, emf

I am working on a school project with Xtext. My task is to get the objects that are generated based on the dsl that I create with Xtext and send them into a cloud repository.
Can someone help me and show me the files where these objects are stored?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O22V0.jpg)

Comment: It is not clear from your question what exactly you want to send to the cloud repository. Some generated source code? Some serialzation from the EMF model? From the whole project? Or some specific part?

Comment: I need to know where is located the code generated for this language that was created. I am adding an image to make it more clear

Comment: In this case the code behind Notes.gvfile where is located by default?

Comment: there is no "generated sourcecode". the ast only exists in memory during build and editing. so what do you actually want to do?

Comment: If you look at the image there is an outline tree that shows the elements of the domain specific language that is created by the user. I want to migrate these elements in the format of an abstract syntax tree into a cloud storage

Comment: but in which context? during clean build. by rightklick a file or the editor? ......

Comment: for that https://www.dietrich-it.de/xtext/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu.html might be a starting point (do whatever you want with the ast instead of calling the generator)